# Easy to follow beginners tutorial for Titanium mobile/studio

Tags: titanium-mobile

I'm new to Titanium mobile as well as titanium studio, but have heard good things about it.

Can anybody recommend some easy to follow tutorials for beginners? I am also new to Mac - and javascript,- so go easy on me :)

Comment: I agree, it is perhaps not very specific, but I think it is very helpful nevertheless

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here are few links you can follow:

[1- Titanium Wiki](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Quick_Start)

[2- Seven days with Titanium](http://cssgallery.info/seven-days-with-titanium-day-1-windows-views-navigation-and-tabs/)

[3- Titanium WareHouse](http://www.titaniumtips.com/titanium/warehouse.php)