# To design a login page usingTitanium appelerator

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

I have tried to design a login page using Titanium Appcellerator docs. I am not able to understand the docs properly. Can someone help me with any tutorial links on how to store the user's values in database and how to access them and login the user?

Comment: why dont you try for yourself. if you fail , post your tried code here. you will get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to mobile development and how things work, well it will take a little time to get around. Actually once you get familiar with Titanium it will be a piece of cake. Take your time in going through the docs.

This question is a possible duplicate of,

[Easy to follow beginners tutorial for Titanium mobile/studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301405/easy-to-follow-beginners-tutorial-for-titanium-mobile-studio)

After learning a bit you may find this website very helpful to learn how to do things in Titanium.

http://www.titaniumtutorial.com/

We hope you will like Titanium as we do.